# wxPython - How to "highlight" an TextCtrl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

In my GUI i use TextCtrls for User Inputs. The tool guides the user through some steps where different Inputs are mandatory. So, if a TextCtrl is mandatory but empty i want to highlight them as common on many tools and websites with an Red Border. 
After some research i noticed that this isn't possible without creating an Custom widget.

So is there a "standard" way to highlight it in some ways other than changing its background color?

Minimal example if somebody need to test anything:

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        test_text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(pnl)        

        self.SetSize((350, 250))
        self.Centre()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My native solution would be to place each textctrl over their own panel that can be colored. This would create the illusion of a border around each textctrl. Here's an example:

```
import wx, traceback

# sets the width of the highlight border
HIGHLIGHT_WIDTH = 2
HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = (255, 0, 0)


class Mainframe(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.bg_color = wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_MENU)
        self.highligt_color = wx.Colour(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="Highlight TextCtrl Test", size=wx.Size(500, 300),
                          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(self.bg_color)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.textctrl_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.textctrl_panel.SetBackgroundColour(self.highligt_color)

        textctrl_panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.textctrl_panel)
        textctrl_panel_sizer.Add(self.textctrl, 0, wx.ALL, HIGHLIGHT_WIDTH)

        self.textctrl_panel.SetSizer(textctrl_panel_sizer)
        self.textctrl_panel.Layout()
        textctrl_panel_sizer.Fit(self.textctrl_panel)
        main_sizer.Add(self.textctrl_panel, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        self.textctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_text)

        # to reduce flickering
        self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)
        self.CenterOnScreen(wx.BOTH)
        self.Show()

    def on_text(self, event):
        """ triggered every time the text ctrl text is updated, schedules validate_text() to run after the event """
        event.Skip()
        wx.CallAfter(self.validate_text)

    def validate_text(self):
        """ sets the textctrl panel background color to give the appearance
        of a red highlight if there is no text in the text ctrl """
        color = self.bg_color if self.textctrl.GetValue() else self.highligt_color
        self.textctrl_panel.SetBackgroundColour(color)
        # force the window to repaint
        self.textctrl_panel.Refresh()


try:

    app = wx.App()
    frame = Mainframe()
    app.MainLoop()
except:
    input(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Little bit sad, that this is the or one of the best things to do :-D